# find a value in JSON stringify array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, associative-array

i want to find a value  in  JSON stringify array

```
[{"id":"432","temperature":"1","humidity":"1","createat":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"id":"433","temperature":"22.00","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 19:49:57"},{"id":"434","temperature":"22.40","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 19:52:02"},{"id":"435","temperature":"22.40","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 19:55:26"},{"id":"436","temperature":"22.00","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 19:58:50"},{"id":"437","temperature":"22.00","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 20:02:14"},{"id":"438","temperature":"22.50","humidity":"51","createat":"2015-10-11 21:23:15"},{"id":"439","temperature":"22.50","humidity":"50","createat":"2015-10-11 21:24:37"},{"id":"440","temperature":"22.50","humidity":"51","createat":"2015-10-11 21:26:17"},{"id":"441","temperature":"22.50","humidity":"51","createat":"2015-10-11 21:26:41"}]
```

my idea to get this value is to know  if what i am adding is not already added

Comment: Iterate and check the properties.

Comment: why don't you just `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: @Guillermo do you want to check the value in `javascript` ? and add any code you have tried to get the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// stringified JSON
stringifiedJson = '[{"id":"432","temperature":"1","humidity":"1","createat":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"id":"433","temperature":"22.00","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 19:49:57"},{"id":"434","temperature":"22.40","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 19:52:02"},{"id":"435","temperature":"22.40","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 19:55:26"},{"id":"436","temperature":"22.00","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 19:58:50"},{"id":"437","temperature":"22.00","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 20:02:14"},{"id":"438","temperature":"22.50","humidity":"51","createat":"2015-10-11 21:23:15"},{"id":"439","temperature":"22.50","humidity":"50","createat":"2015-10-11 21:24:37"},{"id":"440","temperature":"22.50","humidity":"51","createat":"2015-10-11 21:26:17"},{"id":"441","temperature":"22.50","humidity":"51","createat":"2015-10-11 21:26:41"}]';

// parse the stringified JSON into a JavaScript object
parsedJson = JSON.parse(stringifiedJson);

// the object in the array you want to check
number = 0

// check if the property exists
if(typeof parsedJson[number].humidity !== 'undefined') {
  // set the property
  parsedJson.humidity = 1;
}

// stringify your object again
stringifiedJson = JSON.stringify(parsedJson);
```

EDIT: here is a `propertyExists` function:

```
var propertyExists = function(stringifiedJson, id, property) {
  // parse the stringified JSON into a JavaScript object
  parsedJson = JSON.parse(stringifiedJson);
  // check if the property exists for a given ID
  for(var i = 0; i < parsedJson.length; i += 1) {
    if(parseInt(parsedJson[i].id) === parseInt(id)) {
      return (typeof parsedJson[i][property] !== 'undefined')
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// stringified json
var stringifiedJson = '[{"id":"432","temperature":"1","humidity":"1","createat":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"id":"433","temperature":"22.00","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 19:49:57"},{"id":"434","temperature":"22.40","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 19:52:02"},{"id":"435","temperature":"22.40","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 19:55:26"},{"id":"436","temperature":"22.00","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 19:58:50"},{"id":"437","temperature":"22.00","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 20:02:14"},{"id":"438","temperature":"22.50","humidity":"51","createat":"2015-10-11 21:23:15"},{"id":"439","temperature":"22.50","humidity":"50","createat":"2015-10-11 21:24:37"},{"id":"440","temperature":"22.50","humidity":"51","createat":"2015-10-11 21:26:17"},{"id":"441","temperature":"22.50","humidity":"51","createat":"2015-10-11 21:26:41"}]';

console.log(propertyExists(stringifiedJson, 432, 'humidity'));
```

Comment: i only want to know if exits a value inside

Comment: That's what this answer is telling you. The part that says `// check if property exists`.

Answer (score 1):

```
....

var jsonArray = [{"id":"432","temperature":"1","humidity":"1",.....

var isPresent = false;
$.each(jsonArray, function(i,v){
    if(jsonArray[i].id == newObject.id){
        isPresent = true;
    }
});
if(!isPresent){
    jsonArray.push(newObject);
}

....
```

Comment: only i want to find a word in array @mike

Comment: By 'word', are you talking about the words "id, temperature, humidity...etc"? Because those are properties, which can be found using `hasOwnProperty()`

Comment: with 'word' i am talking about the value indise temperature id or  humidity @A.O

Comment: There's no jQuery tag or request, there is also the built–in *Array.prototype.forEach* since ES5. More appropriate is [*Array.prototype.some*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.some). Code–only answers aren't liked, you should explain why your answer fixes the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to find a value in JSON stringify array

You don't say what value you are trying to find. What you've posted is an Array literal, not JSON. If you want to iterate over the array to determine if it contains an object with a certain property that has a particular value, you can use [Array.prototype.some](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.some):

```
function hasPropValue(array, prop, value) {
  return array.some(function(obj) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj[prop] === value;
  }
}
```

*some* will iterate only over members that exist, and will stop as soon as the callback returns *true*, otherwise it returns false. If you really do have a string value that is valid JSON, you can do:

```
hasPropValue(JSON.parse(jsonText), 'id', '432');
```

```js
var jsonText = '[{"id":"432","temperature":"1","humidity":"1","createat":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"id":"433","temperature":"22.00","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 19:49:57"},{"id":"434","temperature":"22.40","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 19:52:02"},{"id":"435","temperature":"22.40","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 19:55:26"},{"id":"436","temperature":"22.00","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 19:58:50"},{"id":"437","temperature":"22.00","humidity":"48","createat":"2015-10-11 20:02:14"},{"id":"438","temperature":"22.50","humidity":"51","createat":"2015-10-11 21:23:15"},{"id":"439","temperature":"22.50","humidity":"50","createat":"2015-10-11 21:24:37"},{"id":"440","temperature":"22.50","humidity":"51","createat":"2015-10-11 21:26:17"},{"id":"441","temperature":"22.50","humidity":"51","createat":"2015-10-11 21:26:41"}]'

function hasPropValue(array, prop, value) {
  return array.some(function(obj) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj[prop] === value;
  });
}

document.write(hasPropValue(JSON.parse(jsonText), 'id', '432'));
```